# Execute create_resource after everything has finished or after exec has finished

Tags: puppet

Is it possible to control execution of create_resources function ? Say I have a class and a definition:

```
define do::something($a, $b) {
    exec { .. }
    exec { .. }
}

class do::foo {
    $params = {
        'a' => { .. },
        'b' => { .. }
    }

    exec {'I need to run first': ... }

    create_resources('do::something', $params)
}
```

In my case I use `do::something` to add keys to a key/value store. But I need to first wait for `exec` to refresh this store. If `exec` after `create_resources` than those keys will not be in the the key/value store as the refresh will remove them.

I have tried using the `->` approach and `notify => Exec[]` but I'm unsure how to pass params in this case. `create_resource` has it's own condition weather it will execute but it needs to be called every time just after the `exec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like all Puppet functions, `create_resources()` runs *during catalog building*.  Each catalog is completely built before any resource declared in it is applied, and often on a different machine than the one for which it is intended.  What you appear to be after is not modulating the behavior of `create_resources()`, but rather managing the relative order of application of the resources it adds to the catalog.

And that you can readily do with a chain operator and a resource collector.  For example, add

```
Exec['I need to run first'] -> Do::Something<||>
```

to the body of class `do::foo`.  There are a lot of possible variations on that, and also a few alternative approaches, but I would need details of the specific use case to make stronger or more specific recommendations.